# Solr Suggester text containing -

Tags: solr, autocomplete

I am using Apache Solr Suggester for Auto-complete. When I search with 'DC' I get the response DC-UK_ITP along with other values.

When I search DC-UK_ITP, it is not able to find the value and returns no suggestions.

How should I pass the value DC-UK_ITP so that it is able to find the value correctly?

Or is there any settings I need to do at Solr configuration.

Comment: check your analysers used ..they must be removing the - added in DC-UK...If you could share the fieldTYpe used ..it would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

When configuring the "suggester" component it is always important to keep an eye on "suggestAnalyzerFieldType" parameter from solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    ...
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggest_type</str>
    ...
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Values which were produced at "index-time" (when suggester built its data structures) should correspond and match the values which will be obtained at "query-time" (essentially when you will issue the query).

Considering you have following set-up in schema.xml:

```
<field name="suggest_field" type="suggest_type" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="suggest_type" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Document with

```
 "suggest_field": ["DC-UK_ITP"]
```

will be stored in indices with the following terms:
dc, uk_itp.

In order to have "contains"-based suggester I would recommend considering the AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory lookup as follows:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">infixSuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">suggest_field</str>
    <str name="weightField">price</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggest_type</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Analyzing Infix Lookup will also bring you highlight in the response, which is very handy if you are using it directly from the search-box UI. Matching strategy will allow you to match by any prefix, so you'll be able to match original "DC-UK_ITP" value either by:

- &suggest.dictionary=infixSuggester&suggest.q=dc
- &suggest.dictionary=infixSuggester&suggest.q=uk
- &suggest.dictionary=infixSuggester&suggest.q=dc-uk_itp

Useful resources on the topic:

- [Solr Suggester wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester)
- [FST Lookup vs Infix Suggester Lookup](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/03/04/solr-suggester/)

Comment: Please find below the solrconfig and schema entries: -

Comment: <searchComponent name="suggestMapName" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">suggestMapName</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
   .....................
      <str name="field">mapName_partial</str>
      <str name="payloadField">mapName</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">mapName_text</str>
      <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">mapName_text_suggest</str>
   ......................
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

Comment: From what I understand, solrconfig.xml has similar setting as you mentioned.

Comment: I will make the changes you suggested and try

Comment: it's been a long time, but did you have a chance to give it a try? :)

Answer (score 0):

"Suggester" simply retrieves tokens starting with characters "DC" from a token dictionary corresponding to an indexed field, in this case it retrieves token "DC-UK_ITP". You then make a query to another field, indexed differently, and you use "DC-UK_ITP" as a search term, and this another term dictionary (corresponding to another field) doesn't contain it.